# Spark structured streaming with grouped data - one single microbatch for each group

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

if having grouped stream dataframe data, is it possible in spark structured streaming to process each group in separate single microbatch? Something like this:

```py
dfs = ...
dfs.groupBy(...).writestream...foreachbatch()
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you check if this helps

Comment: Unfortunatley it does not help. At least I don't see how would it help. Anyway thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511437/running-a-function-for-every-batch-of-pyspark-sctructred-stream-without-udf#:~:text=You%20can%20achieve%20this%20using%20the%20foreachBatch,my_foreach_batch(df%2C%20epoch_id):%20update_session_id(session_length%2C%20db_table)%20df.write.format(%22delta%22).mode(%22append%22)%20%5C%20.partitionBy(%22YYYYMMDD%22%2C%22hour%22)

Comment: Plese check this

Comment: Can u show input and output as example pls?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the grouped data separately in micro-batch. If you want your data in separate folders based on the grouped column, you can use the code below.

```py
def batch_oper(df, epoch_id):
  df.groupby(F.col("country")).count() \
    .write.format("csv").mode("append") \
    .partitionBy("country") \
    .save("base_path_of_the_location")

df.writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .foreachBatch(batch_oper) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "base_path_of_the_location/checkpoint") \
  .start()
```

or

```py
def batch_oper(df, epoch_id):
    df.write.format("csv").partitionBy("country").save("dbfs:/part_csvs1/")

streaming_df.groupBy(F.col("country")).count().writeStream.outputMode("complete").foreachBatch(batch_oper).option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/part_csvs/checkpoint").start()
```

Output:

[image]

Here, it creates separate folders for every country and stores the data.

If you want to perform custom operations on grouped data, PySpark doesn't support user-defined aggregate functions, but you can follow the approaches in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817326/how-can-i-define-user-defined-aggregate-functions-in-pyspark) solution.

Comment: Why having separate folders helps?

Comment: You were trying to write grouped data to separately right? Please add your expecting outcome in the question. I will check for it.

Comment: No. I want to write it into the same sink. I just want to process the groups separately.

Comment: In such case you need to repartition the dataframe on group by column and process it.

Comment: Is it guaranteed, that data from one partition will be processed in one single microbatch?

Comment: Yes. In single microbatch are you getting only grouped data or all data? Partition is like processing each of your grouped data parallel. Example when you do partition on any column and you got 3 different partitions then all 3 of them are processed separately in parallel.